# Object is possibly undefined; Typescript; Object

Tags: typescript, express, webstorm

How come that the object is possibly undefined, when it's hard-coded in my file. It is a constant and it never changes. ts-ignore doesn't work either.

```
const expressConfig = {
    app: {
        PORT: 3000,
        standardResponse: `Server running on port ${this.PORT}`
    }
};
export default expressConfig;
```

${this.PORT} seems to be the issue here but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

because its an object literal and not a class.
You'll need to convert your construct to a class first or if you wish to use the object literal construct define port outside of it.